# Basic question on covering maps

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is a covering map of $Y$. Let $y\in Y$ and let $x_1,x_2\in f^{-1}(y)$. We know that for each loop $\alpha$ in $Y$ at $y$, we have a lift $\tilde{\alpha}$ to $X$ such that $\alpha=f\circ\tilde{\alpha}$ where $\tilde{\alpha}(0)=x_1$ (or $x_2$, if chosen).

Here's my question: for any path $\beta$ from $x_1$ to $x_2$ in $X$ ($x_1,x_2\in f^{-1}(y)$, $X$ path connected), $f \circ \beta$ is intuitively a loop in $Y$ based on $y_0$ because $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=y$. How do we prove that this is true?

EDIT: More precisely, pick any $x_1,x_2\in f^{-1}(y)$ and let $\beta:I\to X$ such that $\beta(0)=x_1,\beta(1)=x_2$. Is it guaranteed that $f\circ\beta\in\pi(Y,y)$?

Comment: Yes. Why do you have doubts?

Comment: I thought I was overlooked something - sorry for asking such a trivial question